# Using makefile variable on subdirectory .sh?

Tags: bash, makefile, environment-variables

Is it possible to use variables defined in a .mk file and use them in a .sh file?

In this case, there's a general makefile that includes a .mk file which defines directories that will be used in all of the submakes. This is done with the export command, if I'm not mistaken. An example:

```
export SW_DIR:=$(ROOT_DIR)/software
```

In all of the submakes, I can call this folder using $(SW_DIR), but what about in .sh files? I'm having trouble doing the exact same thing on bash scripts. Is it possible to carry over the environment variable from a makefile to a bash script?

In the main Makefile, the first lines are:

```
export ROOT_DIR:=.
include ./system.mk
```

Then in the system.mk, there's:

```
export SW_DIR:=$(ROOT_DIR)/software
export PYTHON_DIR:=$(SW_DIR)/python
```

And further in, in the .sh file which is in a sub-directory, I call:

```
cp ${SW_DIR}/file.h .
${PYTHON_DIR}/code.py ADDRESS > ADDRESS
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Write a bash script, and try it.

Comment: maybe you also wrote `$(SW_DIR)` in the shell script? it should be `${SW_DIR}` (or just `$SW_DIR` if there's no ambiguity).

Comment: Tried it but the .sh doesn't access the directories. I wrote this code on the .sh file and get the following errors:

`
cp ${SW_DIR}/file.h .
${PYTHON_DIR}/code.py ADDRESS > ADDRESS


cp: cannot stat ‘/file.h’: No such file or directory
../script.sh: line 9: /code.py: No such file or directory
`

Comment: One workaround was to forget the export command and rather include the system.mk in the Makefile which calls the .sh script.